# How to localize Firefox SDK Add-on name and description?

Tags: json, firefox, localization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing an add-on for Firefox and I now wish to localize the name and description of the add-on itself, as visible to the user in the Add-ons Manager menu.

However, the guides I've seen online only seem to mention preferences in package.json and nothing about the name of the add-on or its description. I have tried to apply the suggestions for preferences to the name/description fields and haven't had any success - it will always appear in English.

Is localization of these fields even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this from package.json. Read [bug 661083](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661083) for more details.

However, there is a workaround: Manually edit install.rdf to add `em:localized` properties.

To do this you'll need to use the SDK to package your app into an xpi file. Then open the xpi (it is a zip file) and you'll see install.rdf in the root of the directory.

The MDN article [Localizing extension descriptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localizing_extension_descriptions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Localizing_extension_descriptions) describes what structure the em:localized properties needs to have.

Comment: Thank you for a definitive answer. In attempting to do the above, I can edit the install.rdf file but can't repackage the xpi without corrupting it. However, you've answered my original question so I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's a good point. Have you tried simply zipping the directory? Be sure to give the compressed file a .xpi extension and not .zip, of course.

Comment: I compressed to .zip and then renamed to .xpi?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=661083 has been marked RESOLVED FIXED since September 8. But I still can't figure out how to use the SDK to localize the add-on name and description.

Comment: There was a comment added on 19 Jan, they are not going to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has been added to the [jpm tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) recently (February 2016, see [issue 495](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/pull/495)). Make sure that you use a recent jpm version, then the following code in `package.json` will work:

```
"title": "Default add-on name",
"description": "Default add-on description",
"locales": {
  "de": {
    "title": "Add-on name in German",
    "description": "Add-on description in German"
  },
  "ru": {
    "title": "Add-on name in Russian",
    "description": "Add-on description in Russian"
  },
}
```